# Hover with overlay and not affecting text color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the color of the image darker when it's hovered, and without affecting the color of the text attached to it at the same time. I tried to use `opacity` but it doesn't work as expected.

```css
.imageone {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.imageone:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageone">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG2v9.jpg" alt="" />
  <h2 id="header">A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach 1:**  Using CSS [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), e.g. `filter: brightness(0.5);`

```css
.imageone {
  position: relative;
}

.imageone img {
  transition: filter .25s;
}

.imageone img:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.5);
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageone">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG2v9.jpg" alt="" />
  <h2 id="header">A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>
</div>
```

**Approach 2:**  Using a pseudo element to cover the image with `background-color: rgba();`

```css
.imageone {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imageone:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: background-color .25s;
}

.imageone:hover:before {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageone">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG2v9.jpg" alt="" />
  <h2 id="header">A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>
</div>
```